# Filling a java object from a json object

Tags: java, json

I was wondering if something existed to directly fill the attributes of a java object from a json object?
Something like : 
TotoObject toto = fill(JsonObject);

I'm doing this using getter and setter at the moment, but it's pretty long and it makes my code look like crap when I have an object with a lot of attribute.

Thank you.

Comment: Tried GSON: http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a similar question with an answer that also suggests using GSON. There's a good code snippet in the answer too: [How do I populate List from JSON response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10345303/how-do-i-populate-listobject-from-json-response)