# JSON: Nested Array

Tags: java, json, nested

I have a program that retrieves data from a Database (data store in JSON MySQL).

```
public static int selectData(Connection conn, String db_type) throws SQLException {

     JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();

    String q = "SELECT * FROM common_attr_test";
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(q);
        preparedStatement.execute();
        ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
                String uuid_user = rs.getString("uuid");
                String attributes_uuid = rs.getString("attributes");

                obj.put("uuid", uuid_user);
                obj.put("attributes",  attributes_uuid);  
        }

            System.out.println("JSON Obj: "+obj);

    return 1;
 } // end selectData function
```

I managed to get the object. The output is:

> JSON Obj:

```
 {
  "attributes": "{\"1\": {\"1\": 2, \"2\": 2, \"3\": 3}, \"2\": {\"h4y4/1123\": 4, \"h4yp:/4/1123\": 1, \"h4yyp:/4/1123\": 1, \"httyyyyp:/4/1123\": 1}, \"3\": {\"Chrome|Windows NT 6.1\": 7}, \"7\": {\"2\": 4, \"6\": 1}, \"8\": {\"1\": 1, \"2\": 1, \"3\": 1, \"4\": 1, \"5\": 1, \"6\": 1, \"7\": 1}}",
  "uuid": "izyani1234561"
}
```

I need a suggestion on how I can process the data and put the information in different array/object. For example

```
    array1 - 1:{1:2, 2:2, 3:3}
    array2 - 7:{2:4, 6:1}
    array3 - 8:{1:1, 2:1, 3:1, 4:1, 5:1, 6:1, 7:1}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Jackson Api to achieve this.
You have to create Pojo class same as your json object (Class should have members like 'attributes','uuid').
This are classes you have to use

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory;
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
```

And code

```
ObjectMapper objMapper=new ObjectMapper();
JsonFactory jfactory = new JsonFactory();
JsonParser jParser=jfactory.createJsonParser(jsonString); //json Object as String

Mapperclass mapper=objMapper.readValue(jParser,Mapperclass.class);// Mapperclass is Pojo for your jsonObject
```

Now you can use getter methods of Mapperclass to get you json attributes in java object or Arrays etc  like

```
 String uuid=mapper.getUuid();
```

Comment: is there any other way instead of using POJO?

Comment: Thank you.Manage to solve the problem. I'm using  org.json library.