# Generic code to read API response

Tags: java, json

I need generic code to read response.
In below response I want to print all the jsonobjects ( response header and response ) as well as all the json array present in those objects with all strings or child nodes present in those arrays. Below is just an example , I want to make it generic so that when will hit any API will get their respective json objects , arrays and values.

**Response** :

```
{"responseHeader":{"status":0,"QTime":0,"params":{"q":"banga","df":null,"fl":"ID,Name,rank,cc,geoloc","json":"","sort":"rank desc,score desc","fq":"cc:IND OR cc:NPL","wt":"json"}},"response":{"numFound":10,"start":0,"docs":[{"ID":122,"Name":"Bangalore","cc":"IND","rank":4043,"id":null},{"ID":1304,"Name":"Bangalore Intl Airport","cc":"IND","rank":8,"id":null},{"ID":94616,"Name":"Bangarupalem","cc":"IND","rank":1,"id":null},{"ID":198581,"Name":"Bangarapet","cc":"IND","rank":0,"id":null},{"ID":94208,"Name":"Bangana","cc":"IND","rank":0,"id":null},{"ID":199245,"Name":"Bangaon","cc":"IND","rank":0,"id":null},{"ID":81774,"Name":"Bangalore Package","cc":"IND","rank":0,"id":null},{"ID":78517,"Name":"Bangalore Sight Seeing","cc":"IND","rank":0,"id":null},{"ID":202000,"Name":"Wonderla Amusement Park(bangalore)","cc":"IND","rank":0,"id":null},{"ID":202037,"Name":"Wonderla (bangalore) Package","cc":"IND","rank":0,"id":null}]}}
```

Code I have written :

```
String soapEndPointURL= "https://www.redbus.in/Home/SolarSearch?search=banga";

          HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

              GetMethod method = new GetMethod(soapEndPointURL);
              int response_code = client.executeMethod(method);
              System.out.println("Response : " + response_code);
              System.out.println("HTTP GET request status: " + method.getStatusText());
              String response_text= method.getResponseBodyAsString();
              System.out.println(response_text);
            try{
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(response_text);
              JSONObject myResponse = jsonObj.getJSONObject("response");
              JSONArray tsmresponse = (JSONArray) myResponse.get("docs");

              ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

              for(int i=0; i<tsmresponse.length(); i++){
                 String s = tsmresponse.getJSONObject(i).getString("Name");
                 System.out.println(s);
              }
    }
            catch(JSONException e)
            {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
}
```

Comment: you know that, JSONObject gives you a method optJSONObject (and optJSONArray). So you can use if (myResponse != null) do whatever

Comment: With which Java version are you working with? (You could simplify your code) And is there any reason not to use an already existing library?

Comment: You can view similar answer @ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51941358/json-nested-array/51942831#51942831

Answer (score 0):

You could rely on `Jackson`'s `ObjectMapper` implementation for achieving this, wherever you'd need a generic way of implementation (to parse `JSON` responses). For this, you will have to come up with the required datamodels (Java POJOs) that are part of the response that you'd be receiving.

You can generate all the datamodels before hand and pass that response datamodel to your `ObjectMapper` object to traverse through the response seamlessly.

You could use online tools as like [this](http://jsongen.byingtondesign.com/), to generate the datamodels based on your `JSON` response. To be precise, this is just a sample implementation and there can be many more better ways (but for a smaller implementation or a poc - this should be sufficient).

You could change your implementation to something like this:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.GetMethod;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.rest.json.response.models.RedBusJSONResponse;

public class JSONResponseParse {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String restEndpoingURL = "https://www.redbus.in/Home/SolarSearch?search=banga";
        try {
            GetMethod method = new GetMethod(restEndpoingURL);
            String getMethodResponse = method.getResponseBodyAsString();
            System.out.println(getMethodResponse);

            ObjectMapper responseMapper = new ObjectMapper();
            RedBusJSONResponse redbusResponse = responseMapper.readValue(getMethodResponse, RedBusJSONResponse.class);
            System.out.println(redbusResponse.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Here the `RedBusJSONResponse` class is built on the following JSON response that was provided earlier:

```
{
    "responseHeader":{
        "status":0,
        "QTime":1,
        "params":{
            "q":"banga",
            "df":null,
            "fl":"ID,Name,rank,cc,geoloc",
            "json":"",
            "sort":"rank desc,score desc",
            "fq":"cc:IND OR cc:NPL",
            "wt":"json"
        }
    },
    "response":{
        "numFound":10,
        "start":0,
        "docs":[
            {
                "ID":122,
                "Name":"Bangalore",
                "cc":"IND",
                "rank":4043,
                "id":null
            },
            {
                "ID":1304,
                "Name":"Bangalore Intl Airport",
                "cc":"IND",
                "rank":8,
                "id":null
            },
            {
                "ID":94616,
                "Name":"Bangarupalem",
                "cc":"IND",
                "rank":1,
                "id":null
            },
            {
                "ID":198581,
                "Name":"Bangarapet",
                "cc":"IND",
                "rank":0,
                "id":null
            },
            {
                "ID":94208,
                "Name":"Bangana",
                "cc":"IND",
                "rank":0,
                "id":null
            },
            {
                "ID":199245,
                "Name":"Bangaon",
                "cc":"IND",
                "rank":0,
                "id":null
            },
            {
                "ID":81774,
                "Name":"Bangalore Package",
                "cc":"IND",
                "rank":0,
                "id":null
            },
            {
                "ID":78517,
                "Name":"Bangalore Sight Seeing",
                "cc":"IND",
                "rank":0,
                "id":null
            },
            {
                "ID":202000,
                "Name":"Wonderla Amusement Park(bangalore)",
                "cc":"IND",
                "rank":0,
                "id":null
            },
            {
                "ID":202037,
                "Name":"Wonderla (bangalore) Package",
                "cc":"IND",
                "rank":0,
                "id":null
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Where is the RedBusJSONResponse class implementation?

Comment: You will have to generate these POJO classes as mentioned earlier. I have provided a link which I used to generate these POJOs based on the response that you've shared earlier

Answer (score 0):

Json-Jackson library is your best bet. Assuming you got your JSON String you can do this

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

            Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();

            // convert JSON string to Map
            map = mapper.readValue(jsonString, new TypeReference<Map<String, String>>(){});

            System.out.println(map);
```

The code is taken from this [tutorial](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-map-to-from-json-jackson/). Method `readValue()` may also take URL or InputStream as first parameter. JSON-Jackson library (also known as Faster XML) is de-facto standard for parsing JSON. It is fast and stable. Here is [Javadoc](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html) page for `ObjectMapper` class. Here is [Maven repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core) to get Json-Jackson

Comment: Out of curiousity, I modfied the implementation and I see a `NullPointerException` :(

Comment: You will need to give me the stacktrace, but jsonString is the variable that should hold your response. Otherwise it would be null that would cause NullPointerException

Comment: As I said, I modified the program based on your answer and I'm facing a NPE. This is the stacktrace: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory.createParser(JsonFactory.java:879)
 at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2877)
 at com.rest.json.response.parse.JSONResponseParse.main(JSONResponseParse.java:29)

Comment: Your problem lies in JSONResponseParse.java:29 where you call method readValue. See if you pass some null value into the method

Answer (score 0):

```
I got solution but now again i'm not getting how to identify that particular object is an array or not.. (Isarray() method not working for `jsonarray`)

package Test.API;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpException;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.GetMethod;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class RedBusJSONResponse {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws HttpException, IOException {
        String soapEndPointURL = "https://www.redbus.in/Home/SolarSearch?search=banga";

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        GetMethod method = new GetMethod(soapEndPointURL);
        int response_code = client.executeMethod(method);

        String response_text = method.getResponseBodyAsString();
        System.out.println(response_text);
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(response_text);
            System.out.println(jsonObj);
            JSONArray mainKeyArr =  jsonObj.names();
            System.out.println(mainKeyArr);

            for (int i=0;i<mainKeyArr.length();i++) {
                String mainkey = mainKeyArr.get(i).toString();
                JSONObject subKeyArr = jsonObj.getJSONObject(mainkey);
                JSONArray subTwoKey = subKeyArr.names();
                System.out.println(subTwoKey);
                //Need to write code to identify whether object is an array or not
            }
           }
            catch (JSONException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}


getting output is :

["response","responseHeader"]
["docs","numFound","start"]
["QTime","params","status"]
```