# JSONObject["sum"] not found while parsing JSON in Java

Tags: java, json, api, parsing

I have a problem. I wrote the JSON parsing code, but it gives me an error. I don't understand what the problem is. String result is JSON.I need to output the amount value from sum. Returns an error: "JSONObject["sum"] not found."

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);
JSONObject bpi = json.getJSONObject("sum");
String uuu = bpi.getString ("amount");
System.out.println(uuu);
```

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "txnId": 20071336083,
            "personId": 1,
            "date": "2020-10-21T20:10:56+03:00",
            "errorCode": 0,
            "error": null,
            "status": "SUCCESS",
            "type": "IN",
            "statusText": "Success",
            "trmTxnId": "403300256",
            "account": "xxx",
            "sum": {
                "amount": 10,
                "currency": 643
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: first retrieve the data node (array) and then try retrieving the sum node on  data[0]

Comment: Use [JsonNode](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html) with [JPointer](https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-appsawg-json-pointer-03). Like explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52072452/1485527).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `sum` element is deep below the structure. But your code is expecting it to be under the root object.
Your code is assuming the json is in structure:

```
{
    "sum": {
        "amount": 10,
        "currency": 643    
    }
}
```

But your json data is in following structure:

```
{ //ROOT JSONObject
  "data": [ // JSONArray
    { //JSONObject - first element of array index 0
      "account": "xxx",
      "sum": { //JSONObject
        "amount": 10,  //value
        "currency": 643
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

So, you need to read it properly:

```
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);
        JSONArray data = json.getJSONArray("data");
        JSONObject el = (JSONObject) data.get(0);
        JSONObject sum = el.getJSONObject("sum");
        String uuu = sum.getString("amount");
        System.out.println(uuu);
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the very detailed explanation. But your code returned: JSONObject["amount"] not a string.

Comment: can you post your JSON data that you are using?

Comment: The one that you posted on the question is not valid json

Comment: Oh, I was stupid. The amount key has an int value, not a string. Thank you very much for your help. Hello from Russia.

Comment: Great. Can you post a valid json to the question for the future reference? Hello from Nepal

Comment: JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);
                    JSONArray data = json.getJSONArray("data");
                    JSONObject el = (JSONObject) data.get(0);
                    JSONObject sum = el.getJSONObject("sum");
                    int uuu = sum.getInt ("amount");
                    System.out.println(uuu);

Comment: JSON data that you are parsing. Because the one that you posted on the question is not valid JSON