# How to convert JSOnObject to Array

Tags: java, android, json, android-studio

i´m new to JSON and when trying to fetch data i'm getting the following error `E/Volley: com.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException:`

**Edit:**

Full StackTrace:

```
2020-11-10 20:06:48.606 10505-10505/com.madcoderz.jsonparsing E/Volley: com.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException: Value {"message":{"affenpinscher":[],"african":[],"airedale":[],"akita":[],"appenzeller":[],"australian":["shepherd"],"basenji":[],"beagle":[],"bluetick":[],"borzoi":[],"bouvier":[],"boxer":[],"brabancon":[],"briard":[],"buhund":["norwegian"],"bulldog":["boston","english","french"],"bullterrier":["staffordshire"],"cairn":[],"cattledog":["australian"],"chihuahua":[],"chow":[],"clumber":[],"cockapoo":[],"collie":["border"],"coonhound":[],"corgi":["cardigan"],"cotondetulear":[],"dachshund":[],"dalmatian":[],"dane":["great"],"deerhound":["scottish"],"dhole":[],"dingo":[],"doberman":[],"elkhound":["norwegian"],"entlebucher":[],"eskimo":[],"finnish":["lapphund"],"frise":["bichon"],"germanshepherd":[],"greyhound":["italian"],"groenendael":[],"havanese":[],"hound":["afghan","basset","blood","english","ibizan","plott","walker"],"husky":[],"keeshond":[],"kelpie":[],"komondor":[],"kuvasz":[],"labrador":[],"leonberg":[],"lhasa":[],"malamute":[],"malinois":[],"maltese":[],"mastiff":["bull","english","tibetan"],"mexicanhairless":[],"mix":[],"mountain":["bernese","swiss"],"newfoundland":[],"otterhound":[],"ovcharka":["caucasian"],"papillon":[],"pekinese":[],"pembroke":[],"pinscher":["miniature"],"pitbull":[],"pointer":["german","germanlonghair"],"pomeranian":[],"poodle":["miniature","standard","toy"],"pug":[],"puggle":[],"pyrenees":[],"redbone":[],"retriever":["chesapeake","curly","flatcoated","golden"],"ridgeback":["rhodesian"],"rottweiler":[],"saluki":[],"samoyed":[],"schipperke":[],"schnauzer":["giant","miniature"],"setter":["english","gordon","irish"],"sheepdog":["english","shetland"],"shiba":[],"shihtzu":[],"spaniel":["blenheim","brittany","cocker","irish","japanese","sussex","welsh"],"springer":["english"],"stbernard":[],"terrier":["american","australian","bedlington","border","dandie","fox","irish","kerryblue","lakeland","norfolk","norwich","patterdale","russell","scottish","sealyham","silky","tibetan","toy","westhighland","wheaten","yorkshire"],"vizsla":[],"waterdog":["spanish"],"weimaraner":[],"whippet":[],"wolfhound":["irish"]},"status":"success"} of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray
```

**JSON Data**: https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/list/all

I've been diggin a lot here at SO but can´t seem to find the correct approach

**Here is the code i've writen so far:**

```
 private void getData() {
    final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    progressDialog.show();

    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(url, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);

                    Article article = new Article();
                    article.setImage(jsonObject.getString("image"));
                    article.setTitle(jsonObject.getString("title"));
                    article.setBody(jsonObject.getString("body"));
                    articles.add(article);


                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
            adaptor.setData(articles);
            adaptor.notifyDataSetChanged();
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e("Volley", error.toString());
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
}
```

}

Comment: Please post the full stacktrace. Also, what's the structure of the input json? Can you post a sample json?

Comment: I just edited the question

Comment: Your code expects a  JSON format that way off than the JSON on stacktrace. You need to 1) confirm if that's the JSON data you want to process. 2) update the JSON parsing code to match with expected JSON data.

Comment: See this for an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64487910/607637

Comment: Use this may be it works.     JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);
 JSONArray obj= json..getJSONObject("message")
 JSONArray  affenpinscherArray=obj.getJSONArray("affenpinscher");
 JSONArray  africanArray=obj.getJSONArray("african");

Answer (score 0):

Te answer is that i was using the wrong URL and the JSON call was expecting a JSONArray instead of a JSONObject. Here is the code that solved the problem:

```
private void fetchElements(){
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    JsonObjectRequest objectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, JSON_URL,
            null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

            try {
                JSONArray breedsList = response.getJSONArray("message");
                for (int i=0; i < breedsList.length(); i++){

                    Cat cat = new Cat();
                    cat.setCatBreed(breedsList.getString(i));

                    cats.add(cat);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
            catAdapter = new CatAdapter(getApplicationContext(), cats);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(catAdapter);
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
    requestQueue.add(objectRequest);
}
```